# CSV list as input parameter in QGIS 3.0 Processing Modeler

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, csv, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I have CSV list with XY coordinates (company and its competitors) which I want to input into simple QGIS Processing model. From this list the model creates and styles two spatial layers.

Everything works well with one exception. I have the input CSV list set up to fixed directory path (see screenshot no. 1). I would like if the model allowed me to select the path to the CSV list when I run the model (see screenshot no. 2).

Does anyone know how to set up a CSV list as an input parameter to QGIS processing model?

[image: QGIS Model Editing Mode]
[image: QGIS Model User Interface]

Comment: have you tried using a string variable for the file path?

Comment: @csk: Could you provide me with an example how would that go, please?

Comment: Actually it needed to be a vector layer parameter, not a string parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add vector layer parameter
[image]

Use this parameter as input for algorithm

[image]

Run the model - it will ask you to select a file for the vector layer parameter

[image]

Comment: Yes, for custom input of CSV table you need to select "Vector Layer" as input parameter. This answer is correct. Thanks